# change MenuItem title from onCreateOptionsMenu

Tags: android, menu, menuitem

I have on my app menu in side menu like this code:

**main.xml**

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
    <item 
        android:id="@+id/menu" 
        android:showAsAction="always"
        android:title="@string/menu">
        <menu>
            <item android:id="@+id/edit" 
        android:title="@string/edit" 
        android:icon="@android:drawable/ic_menu_edit"/>

        </menu>
    </item>
</menu>
```

**MainActive.java**

```
boolean isEdit=false;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.history);
        SharedPreferences sp = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getBaseContext());
        isEdit=sp.getBoolean("isEdit", false);
    }
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(android.view.Menu menu) {
        android.view.MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
         if(isEdit)
            // change R.id.edit title to "test1"
        return true;
    }
```

How I can change R.id.edit title from if(isEdit) condition ?!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should be able to do it like this:

```
menu.findItem(R.id.menuitemname).setTitle(R.string.foo);
```